# Dynamically position absolute element on game map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found myself stuck with this problem: I have game map with following code

## Code

```css
.content-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  align-self: auto;
  background-color: #44362D;
}
.content-inner-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9glDQ.jpg"); /* map.png */
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
          box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.content-inner-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
}
#position {
  width: 4%;
  height: 6.11979%;
  background-color: #FF503C;
  border: 3px solid #90EE90;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px #87CEEB;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scaleY(0.75);
  left: 85%;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-right">
  <div class="content-inner-top">
    <div id="position"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-inner-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to absolute position `#position` element on game map, but, I find it impossible because every time I resize browser window height, element goes to another place. Images are shown below.

## Images

### 1<sup>st</sup> image (normal window)

[image: normal window]

### 2<sup>nd</sup> image (resized window)

[image: resized window]

What should I do? I cannot find solution via javascript nor jQuery either...

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Images are broken, could you mirror them on imgur or upload them through the imgur client in the question editor?

Comment: is your position is some what approximate or accurate enough to be placed there?

Comment: @Thiyagesh: Could you convert these images to imgur images, because the hosting site is categorized as a content sharing site and can be blocked by security nets. Just post the links in a comment, thanks.

Comment: Images are here now: http://imgur.com/wLJ1Pnt,ZNfpReK#0

Element "#position" is circle which need to be placed on exact place in image so it could be active later...

Comment: hi andrija no reply for comments?...

Comment: @Thiyagesh I cannot figure out what are you asking. Red dot should  be always placed in ex. on  town but on resize, red dot is "walking" up and down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your layout in order to achieve this behavior
First of all you need to add your map as an `img` and created a holder for it

```
<div class="content-right">
    <div class="content-inner-top">
        <div class="map-holder">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wLJ1Pnt.jpg" class="content-inner-map" />
            <div id="position"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-inner-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

After that it is a matter of css:

added

```
.content-inner-map {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.map-holder {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.content-inner-top:after {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
}
```

Altered

```
.content-inner-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

#position {
    width: 4%;
    height: 6.11979%;
    background-color: #FF503C;
    border: 3px solid #90EE90;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px #87CEEB;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scaleY(0.75);
    left: 85%;
    top: 24%;
}
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8oL6k6w/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I see that there's a top in 'px' but when you decrease the size of window, the image is smaller not only in width but also height. That's why the pointer went down.
The percentage 'left' property seems to work fine. If you want to use also percents for 'top' property (which could solve the problem), you have to explicitly define the height of the element (the image in your case). You can do that with jQuery for example most easily like this (given that you have an #image element):

```
$('#image').height($('#image').height());
```

Then you can add a resize handler and reassign new height. You may have to remove the previous height, so the whole would be something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#image").css("height","");
    $('#image').height($('#image').height());
});
```

Then you should be able to use css top property in percents and it would be working after window resize.

Comment: is #image element element that is pointer or whole map image?

Comment: That's the image. You have a relatively positioned element (the map) and inside this element you want to position the pointer absolutely (top: X%; left: Y%). The absolute position is relative to the relatively positioned parent. The only thing is that you have to define how high the image is - otherwise top: X% doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use SVG instead, simple code and fully responsive:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 604 568">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="586" height="604" xlink:href="http://i60.tinypic.com/2enrntu.jpg"/>
  <circle cx="400" cy="190" r="20"/>
</svg>
```